# Change bootstrap's menu break point

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design, media-queries, breakpoints

So, I'm working with the latest version and I don't know how change the break point of menu cause I tried change that queries on bootstrap.css (wherein I want a break in width:1010px} :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I change for 1010px but I have o results. In What I'm Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649090/change-bootstrap-menu-breakpoint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486051/change-the-default-responsive-navbar-breakpoint), editing the files manually is 'a horribly laborious task and not recommended'.

Your best options are to either: 
Visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, specify your own breakpoints there, download and use the customised version; or 
Redefine the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in the `less/variables.less` file, and then recompile the CSS.

Comment: Thank mikeybeck but I tried researching how to change the break point only for my navigation bar. It's possible? If I understand right , we can only change the whole (generically).

Comment: Ah, sorry - the variable name should be `@grid-float-breakpoint` rather than `@navbarCollapseWidth`.  Yes, [according to the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) this is the point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed. (i.e. only the navbar is affected)