# Customize Twitter Bootstrap and manage it with npm?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I want to change the break point on a menu in Bootstrap, as described here: [Change bootstrap's menu break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635985/change-bootstraps-menu-break-poin)

I have installed Bootstrap 3.4.4 with npm, and am using it in my source JS using Require.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.4" ...
```

And then I use it in my code like this:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery;
require('bootstrap');
```

It seems that if I want to customize Bootstrap, I have two sensible choices: (i) download a customised version and include it explicitly, or (ii) change the LESS variable in source and recompile the file.

Neither of these seem very compatible with using NPM, unless I'm missing something.

What's the best way to continue to manage packages with NPM, but customize Bootstrap as I want to do?